# Enum Types as explained in Effective Java by Joshua Bloch

Tags: java, enums, effective-java

Please see this [link](http://kulferhat.blogspot.in/2014/08/ej-30-use-enum-instead-of-int-constants.html). Regarding Enums, Mr. Bloch says

> Java’s enum types are classes that export one instance for each
>   enumeration constant via a public static final field.

I read the **Enum Class documentation** but there was **no public static final field**, then how does the above statement hold true. Please explain.
Thanks

Comment: The compiler creates the public static final field for you. Try decompiling the class with javap.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create a `Test.java` file and write `Test enum`:

```
public enum Test {
    Hello
}
```

compile this class: `javac Test.java`,and use `javap Test` to get the compiled class:

```
public final class Test extends java.lang.Enum{
    public static final Test Hello;
    public static Test[] values();
    public static Test valueOf(java.lang.String);
    static {};
}
```

and you can see the `Test` class extends from `Enum` and it has the `public static final Hello` field.

Answer (score 4):

Enum is the base class for all enums. It doesn't contain constants. What contains constants are the concrete enum classes themselves. See for example the [documentation for the enum Locale.Category](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.Category.html). It does contain public static final fields for each enum constant: DISPLAY and FORMAT.